# Is overriding nested class and returning the outer class as base is legal?

Tags: c++, inheritance, visual-c++, language-lawyer

Let's consider the folliwing code:

```
class Base{

protected:
    struct BaseInner{
        virtual void func() = 0;
    };

    BaseInner* ptr;

public:
    void func(){
        if (ptr){
            ptr->func();
        }
    }
};

Base generateBase(){
    class Driven : public Base{

    protected:
        class DrivenInner : public Base::BaseInner{
            virtual void func() override{
                std::cout << "driven class\n";
            }
        };

    public:
        Driven() { ptr = new DrivenInner(); }
    };

    return Driven();
}

int main()
{
    auto base = generateBase();
    base.func();
    return 0;
}
```

(let's leave the memory leak for aside)
the slicing itself, made by `generateBase` is legal by the language, but does it legal to call `ptr->func()` ? logically speaking, the program will ask the vtable for the correct function and call it, but what does the standard says about it? and about the fact that the whole class is defined inside a function?

thanks.

Comment: thanks all! just wanted to make sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `ptr` points to a valid object that is an instance of a subclass of `Base::BaseInner` the code is valid.

The class being defined inside a function only affects the scope of the definition, i.e. where the name of the class is visible.
It's otherwise equivalent to defining the class outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong here other than the leak.

Virtual dispatch must occur.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant limitations on a local class are that:

1. It shall not odr-use a variable with automatic storage duration from an enclosing scope.
2. It shall not have static data members.

Since your class does not do those, I'd say it's good to go.